# One shows fourier transform result but another does not

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I've tried to compare relative velocity variation (dvv) with Ground water(GW) variation.

When I do `fft`, dvv shows reasonable data but GW shows only nan value.

GW value's average is 13, so I normalized them between -1 to 1 but it still shows nan values.

I wonder how to get fft...

About the value of dvv and GW

```
'dvv', Date
2013-09-29   -3.125416e-04
2013-09-30    4.890588e-04
2013-10-01   -2.371517e-04
2013-10-02    1.095513e-05
2013-10-03   -2.729493e-04

'normalized GW:', date
2013-09-29   -0.068246
2013-09-30   -0.136432
2013-10-01   -0.181889
2013-10-02   -0.136432
2013-10-03   -0.045518
```

About the value after fft

```
'dvv fft:', array([-6.36811083e-06+0.00000000e+00j, -1.58287464e-05+2.93493751e-05j,
       -2.52101675e-05+4.09546037e-05j, -1.41381969e-05-8.51555403e-07j,
        4.41795776e-06+4.40403261e-06j,  4.65443040e-07-1.43428029e-06j,
       -8.12204981e-06+6.39966477e-06j,  1.88768593e-06-4.25232078e-06j,
        2.08991725e-06-1.38705266e-06j,  6.83010360e-06+3.22815530e-07j,
        3.05015131e-06-3.32141963e-06j,  4.64790736e-06+5.37213774e-06j])

'GW fft:', array([nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj,
       nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj,
       nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj,
       nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj,
       nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj,
       nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj, nan+nanj])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.

There were several nan values in GW data (full in dvv data).

I use `GW=GW.fillna(method('ffill'))` and solved.

p.s. fillna means fill the nan values with previous/next values (by method).
There is another way which is to use dropna but if I use it, I cannot compare dvv and GW because the number of data is different.